# Re-ordering bars in R's barplot()

Tags: r, sorting, bar-chart

What I want to achieve is exactly the same that was already asked here (and specifically using R's base graphics, not packages like `ggplot` or `lattice`): [Ordering bars in barplot()](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19681586)

However, the solutions proposed there do not seem to work for me. What I need to is the following. Suppose I have this:

```
num <- c(1, 8, 4, 3, 6, 7, 5, 2, 11, 3)
cat <- c(letters[1:length(num)])
data <- data.frame(num, cat)
```

If I generate a barplot using `barplot(data$num)`, here is what I get:

[image]

Now, I want to reorder the bars according to `data$cat`. Following the link I mentioned above, I tried the accepted answer but got an error:

```
num2 <- factor(num, labels = as.character(cat))
Error in factor(num, labels = as.character(cat)) : invalid 'labels'; length 10 should be 1 or 9
```

Then I also tried the other answer there:

```
num <- as.factor(num)
barplot(table(num))
```

But here is what I got:

[image]

So, in this particular case of mine, which is slightly different from that question, **how should I order the barplot so the bars are defined by `data$num` but ordered according to `data$cat`?**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I get the following,

```
num <- c(1, 8, 4, 3, 6, 7, 5, 2, 11, 3)
cat <- c(letters[1:10])
data <- data.frame(num, cat)
barplot(data[order(data[,1],decreasing=TRUE),][,1],names.arg=data[order(data[,1],decreasing=TRUE),][,2])
```

The above code uses the order() function twice (see comments, below).  To avoid doing this the results of the ordered data.frame can be stored in a new data.frame and this can be used to generate the barplot.

```
num <- c(1, 8, 4, 3, 6, 7, 5, 2, 11, 3)
cat <- c(letters[1:10])
data <- data.frame(num, cat)
data2  <- data[order(data[,1],decreasing=TRUE),]
barplot(data2[,1],names.arg=data2[,2])
```

Comment: We posted at the same time: that was exactly what I ended up doing, but your example is much clearer and accurate due to the use of the `decreasing`parameter

Comment: @Juddy pleased to have answered the question.

Comment: @ZheyuanLi the other way to do it would be to assign the re-ordered data to a new data.frame and use this in barplot rather than doing the calculation twice.

Answer (score 26):

you can use ggplot to do this

```
library("ggplot2")
num <- c(1, 8, 4, 3, 6, 7, 5, 2, 11, 3)
cat <- c(letters[1:10])
data <- data.frame(num, cat)    
ggplot(data,aes(x= reorder(cat,-num),num))+geom_bar(stat ="identity")
```

The result is as shown below
[image]

Using base functions

```
df <- data[order(data$num,decreasing = TRUE),]
 barplot(df$num,names.arg = df$cat)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but in this case my question is particularly aimed at base graphics, i.e. using `barplot`.

Comment: Arun, `arrange` and `desc` are not base functions. You might want to use `order` instead

Comment: Ah , yes! My bad. I've made the changes to the answer.

Comment: @Arun also, your second example does not include `data$cat`. But I was able to solve following the general idea of what you said: it is all about reordering the `data` by just doing `order(data$cat)` or, if data.frame is not used, something like `num <- num[order(cat)]. Thanks for the inspiration!

Comment: @ZheyuanLi Btw, just to make it clear I only did not upvote because I still can't. Whenever I get the needed rep, I will be back =)

Comment: `geom_bar(stat ="identity")` can be replaced with `geom_col()` by the way.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you can also use the following if you don't want to put your data in a new dataframe. Just a little simpler.

```
barplot(sort(data$num, decreasing = TRUE))
```

Comment: This method also works when the data argument to barplot() is a table.