# Customize Barplot in base function barplot()

Tags: r, plot

I have a date frame (df), with 2 columns: One numerical and one as.factor() with three levels:

- Pre
- Post
- Blank

I want to make a barplot() with each factor colored to it's respective group (easy), and change the order of the plot so each factor appears next to each other (this is where I'm stuck).

I followed the same logic as I would with a boxplot(), but it does not appear to work the same.  I also tried following examples from several stackoverflow threads, including (but not limited to) this one:

- [Re-ordering bars in R's barplot()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37480949/re-ordering-bars-in-rs-barplot)

But still can't get it to work.

Here is what I've tried, and it works with the boxplot function quite well:

```
df <- read.table("https://pastebin.com/raw/zaETq28M", header = T)

df$Treatment <- as.factor(df$Treatment)

levels(df$Treatment) # note: I would like to display order to be: Pre, Post, then Blank.

df$Treatment <- ordered(df$Treatment, levels = c("Pre","Post","Blank")) # set to the right order

barplot(df$Cq,names.arg = df$Treatment ,col = df$Treatment, ylim=c(0,30), main = "Not the right order bar plot", cex.main=2)
```

In total, I should have 66 individual bars (which I do), but somehow, the order of the graph is not what I set, and the groups are still separated. How can I simply get 3 distinct groups? Meaning, first show all "Pre", then all "post", followed by "blank"

General questions for future posts:

1. How to get a get my graphs to be displayed on Stackoverflow when I post a question? For some reason, my posts never include my graphs.
2. Also, any kind suggestion on using color blind pallet would be great, but I can just do this manually if needed.  Just curious if there is an automatic way of doing it, so I do not need to set it manually in all my graphs

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean this?
First the *Pre*, then *Post* then *blank*. Within each group order is preserved. Legend added with *blank* == *No Treatment*.

```r
df <- read.table("https://pastebin.com/raw/zaETq28M", header = T)

df_Pre <- df[which(df$Treatment == 'Pre'),]
df_Post <- df[which(df$Treatment == 'Post'),]
df_Blank <- df[which(df$Treatment == 'Blank'),]
ddf <- rbind(df_Pre, df_Post, df_Blank)
ddf$color <- c(rep('blue', nrow(df_Pre)), rep('red', nrow(df_Post)), rep('magenta', nrow(df_Blank)))
barplot(ddf$Cq, col = ddf$color, names = rownames(ddf))
legend("bottomleft", 
       legend = c("Pre-Treatmen", "Post-Treatment", 'No Treatment'), 
       fill = c("darkblue", "red","magenta"))
```

[image]

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your time. No, this is a frequency distribution table of my groups.  

My y-axis should be the variable "cq", and the x-axis should have 3 groups:  Pre, Post, and Blank

if you run the code ```table(df$Treatment), you'll see I have 66 total data points, meaning 66 individual barplots. 

Does this help?  Try running my code as is, and you will see what I mean, just the grouping is wrong

Comment: I updated my question to hopefully clarify my point

Comment: @Andy, I hope I understood now - please, see new edit.

Comment: Isn't that cool!  Many thanks for spending time on this :)

Comment: Can you think of a way to have the x-axis line, with tick marks, under each bar, but no numbers?
I first added ```xaxt="n"``` to the barplot command, and then I tried this code: ```xtick<-seq(0, 66, by=1)
axis(1, at=xtick, labels = F)```but was not correct.

Comment: Try this `barplot(ddf$Cq, col = ddf$color, names = rownames(ddf), axis.lty = 1, names.arg = rep('', nrow(ddf)))`

Comment: Hi @marblo : Yes it works.  It's strange that it isn't lined up properly, the tick marks are not in the center of the bars, but thats OK.  I tried a few coding options to get around the issue, but I decided I just will leave it without an x-axis, But even just a black line without ticks would be nicer than no line, I just can't figure it out.