# Is there a way to order a stacked bar plot in Rstudio ggplot such that the bars are ordered based on the increasing or decreasing of a subset?

Tags: r

I would like to order this bar plot based on ascending Inclusive Teaching, which is a level of "variable"

[image]

```
levels(dater$variable)[levels(dater$variable) == "Active Learning Exposure"]  <- "Active Learning"
levels(dater$variable)[levels(dater$variable) == "EPIC_IT_Exposure"]  <- "Formative Assessment"
levels(dater$variable)[levels(dater$variable) == "EPIC_As_Exposure"]  <- "Inclusive Teaching"

ggplot(dater3,aes(Professor, value, fill=variable))+
  geom_bar(stat="identity")+
  theme(axis.ticks.x = element_blank(), axis.text.x = element_blank())+
  ylab("Reported Exposure")+
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("green","blue", "red"))+
  labs(fill = "Evidence Based Teaching Practice")
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Re-ordering bars in R's barplot()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37480949/re-ordering-bars-in-rs-barplot)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Order Bars in ggplot2 bar graph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5208679/order-bars-in-ggplot2-bar-graph)

Comment: This was extensively discussed and answered all over SO.

Comment: @GuedesBF Unfortunately those do not answer my question :( but thank you for your help :)