# Reordering Columns in a Contingency Table / Barplot

Tags: r, bar-chart

I have the following code:

```
set.seed(2022)
x <- sample(c("Freshman", "Sophomore",
"Junior", "Senior"),
300, prob = c(.25, .3, .2, .25), replace = TRUE)

tab <- table(x)
barplot(tab)
```

This produces the following table and graph:

```
x
 Freshman    Junior    Senior Sophomore 
       73        69        77        81
```

[image: Barplot]

I want the bars in the bar graph to be in the following order:

```
ord <- c("Freshman", "Sophomore", "Junior", "Senior")
```

What is the simplest way to change the order of the bars, without using packages?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Re-ordering bars in R's barplot()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37480949/re-ordering-bars-in-rs-barplot)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```r
x <- factor(x, levels = ord)
```

```r
tab <- table(x)
barplot(tab)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! I kept on trying to add levels to the table, and it wasn't working. Since I'm new to R, I didn't realize that I needed to add the levels to the data before I made it into a table.